# XOAuth to Gmail API using Service Account

Tags: c#, gmail-api

Í have this mailer that uses Gmail as provider logged with a organization's user account.
Now, it keeps asking for user consent, but it runs on a background job, so we got an expired token that never gets updated.

That's my current code. It got changed while I'm testing:

`csharp

```
public override async Task SendEmailAsync(SMTPServerConfigurationDetails serverConfigurationDetails, MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
var credentialString = "[JSON_CREDENTIAL_CONTENT]";

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(credentialString).CreateScoped(GmailService.Scope.GmailSend);

var accessToken = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(serverConfigurationDetails.Username, accessToken);

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect(serverConfigurationDetails.ServerIPAddress, serverConfigurationDetails.ServerPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    try
    {
        await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

}`

I've created a service account to use here and downloaded the json key.

But on every test it returns me an error like: "555: 5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye".
I need a help with that.

[image]

Comment: If its asking a user to authenticate your not using service account code